# How to keep open custom infowindow

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw custom infowindow that remains open when map activity launched. Below is the code to keep default marker infowindow open by using marker.showInfoWindow() method. The same i want to do for custom infowindow.

```
private void drawMarker(){

    latLongi = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLongi)
        .title(getString(R.string.sometext))
        .snippet(address)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

        marker.showInfoWindow();
}
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a demo](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html)

You are also able to customize the contents and design of info windows. To do this, you must create a concrete implementation of the InfoWindowAdapter interface and then call `GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()` with your implementation. The interface contains two methods for you to implement: `getInfoWindow(Marker) and getInfoContents(Marker).` The API will first call getInfoWindow(Marker) and if null is returned, it will then call getInfoContents(Marker). If this also returns null, then the default info window will be used.

The first of these `(getInfoWindow())` allows you to provide a view that will be used for the entire info window. The second of these `(getInfoContents())` allows you to just customize the contents of the window but still keep the default info window frame and background.

[for More refer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but this is not the thing that i want, i know how to customize the infowindow, just need help in how to keep custom infowindow opened without touching the marker.

Comment: @gIrL According to the documentation: 'By default, an info window is displayed when a user taps on a marker if the marker has a title set'. This means that this is handled for you by default. and 'Only one info window is displayed at a time'

Comment: yes but i want it to be done without tapping on marker. current location marker's infowindow should be opened automatically when i will navigate to map activity.

Comment: try this: if you have a single Marker you have to check if it isVisible(). If true, check if isInfoWindowShown() (you should get a false here) and call showInfoWindow() (see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html . If you have several Markers you just need to apply this logic inside a for loop

Comment: @gIrL Congrats. Happy Coding